# Problems with column name in Google Colab

Tags: python, split, pandas-groupby, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to build a code to split a list of contacts to random groups without repeting the participants, but it looks like there is a problem with the column name (first_name), basically I import the csv file to Colab and it detects the column lastname, email but not the first_name. I tried to change the column name in excel but it looks like no matter the name is not possible to get the column. I attached the screenshot, but below I will paste the code lines. Also if you have some resources to continue with the split in groups with out repeat the participants will be apreciate it

[image]

```
df1[['first_name']]

df1[['id','lastname','email']]
```

Attached error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-b45bdfc9278a> in <module>()
----> 1 df1[['first_name']]

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis)
   1372                 if use_interval_msg:
   1373                     key = list(key)
-> 1374                 raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
   1375 
   1376             not_found = list(ensure_index(key)[missing_mask.nonzero()[0]].unique())

KeyError: "None of [Index(['first_name'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

Comment: ```df1['first_name']``` are you looking for this?

Comment: @ksohan yes but I'm not sure why is not working. The same function for lastname `df1['lastname']` works without problem

Comment: ```df1['first_name']``` not working? Not ```df1[['first_name']]```! Can you attach the error you are getting?

Comment: @ksohan I attached the error at the end of the post

Comment: Are you using ```df1[['first_name']]```?

Comment: Try to run `df1.columns` , there might be a space there

Comment: @Mohana Actually yeah that was the problem thanks!